# Ada Integer'Width error

Tags: width, ada

I have this Ada package code which theoretically is well written:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Characters.Handling;

package body pkg_procedure is
    procedure Read_Integer(Num : out Integer) is
        Intro : constant Character := ASCII.LF;
        Back : constant Character := ASCII.Del;

        Char : Character;
        Fin : Boolean := False;
        Number : Natural := 0;

        String_Number : String (1 .. Integer'Width – 1);
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Write down a number and press Enter: ");

        while not Fin loop
            Ada.Text_IO.Get_Immediate (Char);
            if Ada.Characters.Handling.Is_Digit (Char) then
                Number := Number + 1;
                String_Number(Number) := Char;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put (Char);
            elsif Char = Intro then
                Fin := True;
            elsif Number > 0 and Char = Back then
                Ada.Text_IO.Put (ASCII.BS & ' ' & ASCII.BS);
                Number := Number + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;

        Number := Integer'Value (String_Number (1 .. Number));
        Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
        Num := Number;

        exception
            when Constraint_Error =>
                Ada.Text_IO.New_line;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Sorry: " & String_Number & " is too long to store it");
                Num := 0;
    end Read_Integer;
end pkg_procedure;
```

When I compile the program I obtain an error on this instruction which says: `binary operator expected`.

I can't fix it. I am totally new to this programming language.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that variable declaration, so you need to provide sufficient context to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that the `-` in

```
    String_Number : String (1 .. Integer'Width – 1);
```

isn’t a plain `-` but a wide character with encoding `e28093` - [EN DASH](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%80%93&mode=char).

I found this because, having seen that various exploratory changes didn’t show the error, I reverted to your original and tried compiling with `-gnatw8` (input is UTF-8) as well as `-gnatl` for mixing messages with the program text, which resulted in

```
13.         String_Number : String (1 .. Integer'Width – 1);
                                                      12
    >>> binary operator expected
    >>> illegal wide character
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I copied it directly from a pdf, and it seems to be copied incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you provided us the wrong part of your code as this

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_Io;

procedure TestInt is
    number : String (1 .. Integer'Width - 1);
begin
    Put_Line("Width=" & Integer'Image(Integer'Width - 1));
end TestInt;
```

works like a charm, if we ignore the warning on number which is not used, and return as expected :

```
Width= 10
```

Please be more precise and provide a full compilable sample.
I might also be interesting to tell us which compiler you use and on which operating system.

Comment: Just edited the question. Hope you find it clear enough